# htop cross compiled for arm, getting the error "Error opening terminal: console." when htop is executed

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, htop

cross compiled htop for arm, 
when htop is executed on the target, I am getting the error **"Error opening terminal: console."**
can anyone help what could be the issue ?

Comment: What is the value of the $TERM variable in your target system?

Answer (score 0):

Just export the following, it works(make sure "terminfo" path is proper)

export TERM=xterm
export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo